# When should I use factory or service in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular services/factory.

This is my simple angular service & factory. Both outputs the same.

```
//defining service
app.service('myService', function () {
this.name = '';
this.setName = function (custName) 
{
this.name = newName;
return this.name;
};
});

//defining factory
app.factory('myFactory', function () {
var serviceObj = {};
serviceObj.name = '';
serviceObj.setName = function (custName) {
serviceObj.name = newName;
};
return serviceObj;
});
```

I have gone few links to get understanding of service vs factory, but I couldn't get it clear.

For the above snippet, what should I use, factory or service.

In general scenario, when should I use factory or service?

> Looking for some clear & concise answer.

Comment: @tpsilva, I read that link but as I said I couldn't get. I am new to it, hence looking for some more clear explainaion

Comment: @aarti what don't you understand specifically? If I were you, I'd re-phrase your question, reference the current duplicate question, and ask specifically what you don't understand so people can guide you. This question is just a duplicate at this point and will be closed.

Comment: The link mentioned by @tpsilva is very clear, what didn't you understand?

Comment: @aarti look at the other answers on that link, the first one is the worst for a newbie trying to understand the concept b/c it doesn't have an illustrations on how to use it.

Comment: @ngDeveloper, Yes,was doing the same. Thank You