# Why only factory is mentioned on angular site

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For last 1 day, I am trying to get clear understanding:-

- What is Service in angular
- Different ways of creating service
- Service vs Factory

Posted a question as well, which was marked duplicate & closed.
[When should I use factory or service in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258488/when-should-i-use-factory-or-service-in-angular)

But I am surprised to see that, on the angularjs official site,
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services 
  they have mentioned only

```
factory('factoryName', ['$window', function(win) {}])
```

Can someone please tell me why so?

Is Factory only the recommended way of creating service by Angular?

Comment: [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

Comment: @Satpal, I have read all that, my question is why on the official site factory is only mentioned not any other method of creating service

Comment: The *guide* (a.k.a. tutorial) focuses on one, the actual API documentation mentions them all: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module

Answer (score -1):

1. Factory is the better way to create service in angular since to instantiate Service, angular calls factory or we can say Service is written on the top of Factory.
2. Factory can also be used to return Value or Class which can be further instantiated

But putting in the mind that moving from angular1.x to angular2.x, we should use Service since they are the function constructor which we will also be using in angular2.x